# How would I got about keeping a file in order when using an async function on it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, discord

so for the discord bot that im using, I'm able to create a custom playlist, and save it as a txt file. I want to read from the text file and queue up each song in it. The problem is thats it's an async function to do it so I lose order even though i want it to stay in order, would there be any way to go about this? This is what my code looks like and I'm not sure where to start to change it to make it keep order from first song to last. The playlist filelooks like this:

thunder

believer

meant to be

country roads take me home

closer remix

mean to me

And the code looks like this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
      var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(actualPlaylist)
      });

      lineReader.on('line', async function(line){
        console.log('Line from file:', line);
        url = line ? line.replace(/<(.+)>/i, '$1') : '';
        console.log(url);
        try{
          var aVideo = await youtube.getVideo(url);
        } catch(error) {
          try{
            var myVideos = await youtube.searchVideos(line, 1);
            var aVideo = await youtube.getVideoByID(myVideos[0].id);
          } catch(myError) {
            console.error(myError);
            return msg.channel.send("Couldnt find any videos by that name.");
          }
        }
        return handleVideo(aVideo, msg, voiceChannel, false); // This is a async function we create down below next to the 'play' function!

      });
```

Comment: Hey its a little unclear what you're trying to keep in order. Your title says you want to keep a file in order but what order? from the first song to the last song?
maybe give us an example of the file you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question a little bit trying to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to make a queue and have it unshift the songs when it started the next one. Something like this maybe. Note this code is untested. Good Luck!

```
/* globals youtube msg handleVideo voiceChannel */
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('./playlist.txt')
})

let songList = []
let called = false

async function getSong (item) {
  let aVideo
  try {
    aVideo = await youtube.getVideo(item.url)
  } catch (error) {
    try {
      const myVideos = await youtube.searchVideos(item.line, 1)
      aVideo = await youtube.getVideoByID(myVideos[0].id)
    } catch (myError) {
      console.error(myError)
      return msg.channel.send('Couldnt find any videos by that name.')
    }
  }
  return handleVideo(aVideo, msg, voiceChannel, false)
}

function videoQueue () {
  if (!songList.length) {
    called = false
    return
  }
  const item = songList.unshift()

  getSong(item)
    .then(() => {
      videoQueue()
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('trying to play next song')
      videoQueue()
    })
}

lineReader.on('line', async function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line)
  const url = line ? line.replace(/<(.+)>/i, '$1') : ''

  songList.push({url, line}) // {url, line} = {url:url, line:line}
  if (!called) videoQueue()
})
```

Comment: I'll try this out as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you :)